# Handle tools password in Python Application

Tags: java, python, security, flask, sqlalchemy

I am developing Python-Flask-SQLAlchemy application by using diffrent tools like Jenkins, JIRA, Stash, Marathon, and few other tools, currently storing all files in config file and use in run time,  now i am facing issue due to security reason, I dont want to store password in config file.

Any suggestion here ? also few application are SSO password.

Regards,
Rayees

Comment: What has your security team suggested as an alternative?

Comment: they dont want to keep in a file, need to find something else

Comment: I suggest you find out what solutions they're okay with rather than making people here give you valid solutions that will get shoot down.